# Not receiving iCloud invites

Tags: ios, calendar

On iCloud.com > Calendar > Preferences > Advanced the "send notification to the app" is enabled

[image]

If my colleague invites me to his calendar by going into iPhone > Calendar > Calendars > CalendarName > Invite person I'm not receiving anything.

The same happens to 3 other people he invited. He's inviting me by writing the email I use to login into iCloud, and when he does my name appears automatically with the word "Pending" below it.

Into my iPhone > Calendar > Incoming it's completely empty.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

- Logging in at https://www.icloud.com
- Go to Calendar -> (Cog) -> Preference -> Advanced
- Beside "Invitations" select "Email To  (Use this option if your primary calendar is not iCloud)".

This may solve your problem if:

1. Someone with an iDevice is sending you the invite.
2. You have an iCloud account.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all accounts involved have security type of two factor authentication and it should work! If they have security questions, you will need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

After several months in contact with Apple support, setting the default calendar on iCloud solved the issue.

To set the default calendar:

1. via browser, go to icloud.com
2. navigate to the calendar
3. create a new (temporary) calendar
4. move the new (temporary) calendar to the first position in the calendars list
5. move your previous calendar back to the first position in the calendars list again
6. delete the new (temporary) calendar
7. make sure you set the invitation notifications back to in-app notifications

Now you should again receive calendar event invitations via in-app notifications on all your devices.